# Room: Warnings: Parameter is never used/Variable is never used

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-room

In my room application I am receiving two warnings in the populateDatabase function:
Parameter 'pbInfoDao' is never used and 
Variable 'pbInfo' is never used

> Task :app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:generateDebugSources
>   Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug
>   Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
>   Task :app:compileDebugSources
>   Task :app:mergeDebugShaders
>   Task :app:compileDebugShaders
>   Task :app:generateDebugAssets
>   Task :app:mergeDebugAssets

How would I fix these?

```
@Entity(tableName = "pbInfo_table")
data class PbInfo(@PrimaryKey
                  var value: Double,
                  var date: Int,
                  var details: String)
```

```
interface PbInfoDao {

    @Query("SELECT * from pbInfo_table")
    fun getListPbs(): LiveData<List<PbInfo>>

    @Query("SELECT value, date, details FROM pbInfo_table")
    fun loadPbInfo(): List<PbInfo>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun update(vararg pbInfo: PbInfo): LongArray

    @Query("DELETE FROM pbInfo_table")
    suspend fun deleteAll()
}
```

db

```
private class PbDatabaseCallback(private val scope: CoroutineScope) : RoomDatabase.Callback() {
            override fun onOpen(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                super.onOpen(db)

                 INSTANCE?.let { database ->
                    scope.launch {
                        populateDatabase(database.pbDao(), database.pbInfoDao())
                    }
                }
            }
            suspend fun populateDatabase(pbDao: PbDao,pbInfoDao: PbInfoDao) {
                pbDao.deleteAll()

                var pb = Pb("Squat")
                pbDao.insert(pb)
                var pbInfo = PbInfo(122.5, 28, "I was feeling on top form today!")
```

Comment: You dont need to write stuff which you dont wanna use or are not using. Its just a simple warning that you have some unused code. It can help you either cleanup your code or verify if you somehow missed to use it. No need to worry about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

these are not errors, they are just warnings that you are not using these values. how do you solve this warning ? you either have to use the variable or function somewhere OR you can safely delete them. Kotlin does this for all unused variables and functions, they will also appear grey:

[image]